# .bash_profile read in the terminal but not in PyCharm

Tags: python, bash, pycharm, tensorflow

very simple python run through in Terminal python, but failed in PyCharm. Based on the message, the PATH I defined in the .bash_profile is not passed in PyCharm. How do I let PyCharm know these PATH?

The correct result in Terminal Python:
[image]

The failure I see in PyCharm:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried putting the entries in your .bashrc instead?

Comment: .bash_profile is executed for login shells, while .bashrc is executed for interactive non-login shells.

Comment: @Tim Sounds correct. Can I just simply copy .bash_profile into .bashrc?

Comment: @Tim I tried just simply copy .bash_profile into .bashrc. Same error occurs in the PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me for a somewhat similar scenario:

- I copied .bash_profile into .bashrc
- In Pycharm's Terminal settings, make sure that the 'Shell integration' option is not checked
- I left 'Shell path' to only have the path to bash (no further
  --rcfile arguments required)

It may help to add an echo with a custom message in your .bashrc file to confirm if indeed this file is being read